# tabpanel dynamic content did not display

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

The issue I am facing is: Why does dynamic data remain in TAB1 and not in TAB2, when both are having the same codes?

I suspect it is something to do with the panel but am not sure.
Thanks for the help.

```html
<div class="modal fade in" id="modalReimburseInfo" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-mid">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                                    <h3 id="H8" runat="server" style="padding-left: 2%" class="modal-title">Reimbursement Details</h3>
                                </div>
                                  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Daily</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Monthly</a></li>
                            </ul>
                                  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upEmpReimburse">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <!-- Navigation Tabs starts -->
                          
                            <!-- Navigation Tabs ends -->
  
                                         <!-- Tab Panes starts -->
                            <div class="tab-content" style="padding-top: 10px">
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                                                        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                                <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Name :</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                                                                            <label runat="server" id="lblrdName" class="control-label"></label>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Department :</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                                                                            <label runat="server" id="lblrdDept" class="control-label"></label>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                      
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                                                        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                                            <asp:GridView ID="grdRbInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="tablesorter table table-bordered table-hover table-striped smallTable tblCtr"
                                                                OnRowCreated="grdRbInfo_RowCreated" >
                                                                <Columns>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Range">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <%#Eval( "DateRange")%>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount ($)">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <%#Eval( "Amt")%>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                </Columns>
                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                           <a onclick="PrintReimburseTab1();" class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-left btnCtrs lnkbtn" style="padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;" ><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                 </div>
                            
                                                </div>
                                              </div> 

                                            </div>
    
                                                     
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                     <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                                                        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                                <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Name :</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                                                                            <label runat="server" id="Label1" class="control-label"></label>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Department :</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                                                                            <label runat="server" id="Label2" class="control-label"></label>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                                                        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="tablesorter table table-bordered table-hover table-striped smallTable tblCtr"
                                                                OnRowCreated="grdRbInfo_RowCreated" >
                                                                <Columns>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Range">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <%#Eval( "DateRange")%>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount ($)">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <%#Eval( "Amt")%>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                </Columns>
                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                           <a onclick="PrintReimburseTab1();" class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-left btnCtrs lnkbtn" style="padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;" ><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                 </div>
                            
                                                </div>
                    
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <!-- Tab Panes ends -->
                                
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Not sure what are the possible factor that is affecting this result.
I added the tab addon base on and example i saw online.
the switching of content in the tab is correct however the data are not disply in the second tab. everything works well in the tab1 but not in tab2

Comment: what do you mean by "remain in code1 and not in code2" ? If you meant to put some data to `<div id="tab2"> ` then the class `active` will make the difference between `tab1` and `tab2`. If that's not your problem please elaborate.

Comment: what code is controlling the tabs? Is it something like bootstrap? Or your own code? Please clarify the exact solution being used. On its own this HTML does nothing, it's just static. It's not clear what you mean by "remain in code1 and not code2". What data? In what circumstances? Describe the steps needed to reproduce the problem, and then the exact issue you face. Sadly we are not mind readers and we also cannot see your screen.

Comment: ok guys @minhhn2910, i will update a more in dept version. thanks guys.

Comment: @ADyson hi sir, i had updated the code. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i found out its the ID which is causing the error. all the label1,label2 i had recreated and replace with the correct ID. Thanks